# WPF + EF: binding an entity and track changes from different contexts

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

I have a WPF application using Entity Framework and two views:

- ProductsListView
- ProductEditView

Considering the following scenario:

1. The **ProductListView** is opened: a DbContext is instantiated, the product list is filled and the **DbContext** is closed.
2. The user selects a product and click in the edit button.
3. The **ProductEditView** is opened: a DbContext is instantiated, the product is loaded by its ID, the fields are filled and the **DbContext** is closed.
4. The user changes the fields and click in the save button: a **DbContext** is instantiated, the product is loaded by its ID, the changes are applied and the **DbContext** is closed.

How the selected product's bindings in the product list would be notified?

---

In a memory context:

1. I just pass the product object from the **ProductListView** to the **ProductEditView**,
2. I bind the fields to the **ProductEditViewModel** properties,
3. When the save button is clicked, I update the product reference.

Since it's the same reference I don't need to do anything to the product list 
be updated.

---

I don't see how I could do the same thing using EF context.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Context, I would suggest you keep the DbContext across all 4 actions. This will save you a lot of hastle.

Not unless your products data is very large and you only retrieve the title and id lets say in initial list fetch, then keep the same DbContext open from time they open **EditView** till they close it. And if they save, EF will find the changes.

It finds changes by comparing the values it retrieved from database, to the values currently set to the entity. By closing the entity context, you are getting rid of the `OriginalValues`.

Comment: Since the application uses a local database (sdf), we take your suggestion and will keep the connection open while it's necessary and across windows, regardless the time it'll stay opened.

Comment: Even if its not local, you would be better of keeping the connection open.... it will save you time on creating the connection each time.